# How to check if attribute exists in mongodb document in forEach function?

Tags: mongodb

I use MongoDB 2.6.2. I need to check in `forEach` if field `name` exists on selected document.

```
db.testData.find(...).forEach(function(x){
// insert code here
})
```

How to check inside `forEach` function if `x` contains field `name` or not ?

Comment: You could also query simply on documents that don't have the field using $exists. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mongo shell is a JavaScript shell, so most of the standard JavaScript methods are supported. You can check if the property exists as you would do on any regular object in JavaScript - by using [hasOwnProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) method:

```
db.testData.find({}).forEach(function(x){
    if (x.hasOwnProperty('name')) {
        // Do something
    }
})
```